# Why Rails' attr_getter is actually redundant

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning the actual functionality of Ruby on Rails' attr_accessor. In the example below, I know it will make both "name" and "name=" methods. Among them, I can test the actual effect of "name=", but even if I remove the entire line of attr_accessor, it does not affect me getting the parameter value of "name". In other words, attr_getter actually does nothing.

But this is theoretically wrong, how can I fix this wrong perception?

```
class HelloWorld
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name = "Old name")   
    @name = name
  end

  def hello          
    puts "Hello, I am #{@name}"
  end

  def intro
    puts "I name is #{@name}"
  end
end

user = HelloWorld.new()           
user.name = "New name"
user.hello                        #=> Hello, I am New name
user.intro                        #=> I name is New name
```

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing to do with Rails. `attr_accessor` is a part of the core of the Ruby language. As for the whole idea of "I can remove `attr_accessor`  and still call `#name` or `#name=`" or whatever you're trying to get at. Nope - this is not something that can actually be reproduced and is most likely a methodology error on your part. You might simply be reopening the class instead of working from a blank slate.

Comment: A oneliner example of this is `class Foo; attr_accessor :bar; end; class Foo; end; Foo.new.bar`.

Comment: So the short answer is - its not Rails. Its not redunant. You're doing something silly.

Comment: "In other words, attr_getter actually does nothing" - you're not using it.

Comment: The “parameter value of `name`” is not the same as the “instance value of `name`“. In the ctor `name` is the parameter—not the attr getter it shadows. In order to exercise the *getter* you need to use it either inside the class when `name` doesn’t refer to something else, or outside an instance method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was mentioned it the comments, it's not about Rails, it's a part of the Ruby core.

`@name` is just an instance variable availbale only inside an instance of `HelloWorld`. When you remove `attr_accessor :name` you won't be able to read or write `@name` from outside (actually you can by using [`instance_variable_get`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_get) and [`instance_variable_set`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_set). But do you really need it?)

```rb
class HelloWorld
  def initialize(name = "Old name")
    @name = name
  end
end

hello_world = HelloWorld.new
```

You can't read it

```rb
hello_world.name
undefined method `name' for #<HelloWorld:0x00007f3125ea51e8 @name="Old name"> (NoMethodError)
```

You can't write it

```rb
hello_world.name= 'New name'
undefined method `name=' for #<HelloWorld:0x00007f3125ea51e8 @name="Old name"> (NoMethodError)
```

It's up to you to decide do you need to give an access to a variable.
If you need only a reader use [`attr_reader`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_reader). If you want to write it use [`attr_writer`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_reader). If you need both, just leave it as it is now with `attr_accessor`.

Comment: In my example it gets called as an instance method. But it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on you.
This is not theoretically wrong. Actually, we have the option of how to work program code. we use the OOP concept in the program code. This code of the program is logically correct.
I think you are saying this your code is correct.

```
class HelloWorld
   def setName(name = "Old name")
        @name = name
   end
   def hello
        puts "Hello, I am #{@name}"
   end
   def intro
        puts "I name is #{@name}"
   end
end
keaton = HelloWorld.new()
keaton.setName("New name")
keaton.hello
keaton.intro

#OUTPUT :
#Hello, I am New name
#I name is New name
```

You know get & set method in a property in other languages. Get method returns the value of the variable and set is assigned a value to the name variable

For example.: **In C#, get set method in a property**

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    private int _name;
    public int Age
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
}
```

same logic in ruby

```
class HelloWorld

    attr_accessor :name

    def initialize
        @name = name
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I get it, to put it simply:

- The original getter and setter define instance methods "name and
  name=" respectively.

```
# getter
def name                 
     @name
end

# setter
def name=(value)    
     @name = value
end
```

- That is, `def name` is not `def self.name`, so it is not a
  class method.
- The `attr_accessor` allows `class HelloWorld` and its new instance to
  use the instance method "name and name=".
- The default value of the method "name and name=" is the specified
  instance variable @name of the initialize.

```
  def initialize(name = "No name")
    @name = name
  end
```

- The methods "hello" and "intro" cannot be reassigned values (like a setter can do), but can have richer output results, such as sentences.